# Javascript: how to call function through variable and pass parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call function from variable i got success but i want to call function and also pass parameters,how to do it. please let me know.

Below i have mention function which is working without parameter.

```
function myfunction(){
alert("hellow world");
} 

var aa= "myfunction";  
window[aa]();   // working
```

```
function myfunction(param){
alert(param);
}

// .....?
```

Comment: @Cerbrus The answer in the question of which you marked this a duplicate is what the OP says he can do already. So while this is a very poor question (OP should have at least tried the obvious), I don't think it's a duplicate of the question that you selected, as that question (and its marked answer) do not address passing parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass arguments to your function where you call `window[aa]()` like so:

```
function myfunction(text){
    alert(text);
} 

var aa= "myfunction";  
window[aa]("Hello Again..."); // just put any arguments in the parentheses.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass it in:

```
window[aa](param)
```

Comment: Really? A answer instead of a close-vote?

Comment: He only has 48k @Cerbrus, why would you think he'd know better? :/

Answer (score 1):

Can you just put the parameter between the parentheses when you call the function?

```
window[aa]("Hello, world");
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
 function myfunction(param){
    alert(param);
 }

    var aa= "myfunction";  
    window[aa]('mk');
```